# fat arrow 'this' scope

Tags: coffeescript, scope, this, arrow-functions

Consider this code

```
 _bindEvents: ->
  @input.bind 'keyup', =>
    @filter($(this).val())
    if $this .val() is ''
      @clearBtn.hide()
    else
      @clearBtn.show()
```

it's clear to me that '@' represents '_this.' so it references the parent scope, but what if i need the 'inner this'.

Like this line:

```
@filter($(this).val())
```

compiles to this:

```
_this.filter($(_this).val()); // $(_this)
```

and I need this:

```
_this.filter($(this).val());  // $(this)
```

Is there a way to do that without using the thin arrow and saving the this reference by hand using a closue (that = this)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK there's no way to do that; and I would warn against it for a couple reasons:

- **ease-of-understanding:** When you use a hash rocket (`=>`), you're effectively telling the reader that you need/want to preserve the current value of `this`; re-introducing a second `this` confuses that.
- **future-compatibility:** From my understanding, the next ECMAScript spec is to support `=>` in a way that it doesn't even introduce a new `this`.  (And I wouldn't be surprised if CoffeeScript directly adopts the new 
  arrow syntax when that feature lands)

A thin arrow w/ explicit referencing will probably make things more clear in the end.

Comment: Thanks, that makes a lot of sense :)

Answer (score 0):

You can always hack this using embedded javascript:

```
`var second_this = this;`
@filter($(second_this).val())
```